# Keycloak - multiple registration pages each own role?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Im familiar with the OOTB registration page that comes with Keycloak, that is described on https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/users/user-registration.html.

Is it possible to have more than one registration page, each with their own associated role?

For example, /registration/artist.html registers a user with an "artist" role and /registration/user.html registers a user with the "user" role.

Comment: Personally, I would rather implement my own registration pages and perform the work of creating the user and assigning the role myself through the keycloak API.

Comment: But it is very hard to keep the flow and the security then. We came up with a solution that is almost fine, but users need to login after registration because the sso capabilities require the proper httponly cookies. It is a deal breaker because UX is too important during registration.